# Why is Doxygen not including private functions in XML files? (and yes, I have EXTRACT_PRIVATE = YES)

Tags: doxygen

Note: The private methods *are* appearing in the HTML files.

In spite of setting all the Configuration file options as recommended to include the private methods, I am not seeing them in the XML files:

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PRIV_VIRTUAL   = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
```

What am I missing? How do I get the private methods to be included in the XML files?

It's a C++ project. Doxygen version 1.9.6

Here is the output from the -x option:

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.9.6
PROJECT_NAME           = "MyProject"
PROJECT_LOGO           = C:/MyFolder/rc32/cc.ico
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = "C:/Doxygen/MyProject"
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = NO
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = NO
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PRIV_VIRTUAL   = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
INPUT                  = c:/MyFolder/MyCode.h \
                            c:/MyFolder/MyCode.cpp
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = *_doxbackup.cpp
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
GENERATE_XML           = YES
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = NO
XML_NS_MEMB_FILE_SCOPE = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = C:\MyFolder
PREDEFINED             = WIN64
```

**Edit: change "documentation" to "XML files".**

Comment: Hard to tell without a small example so we can reproduce the problem (also provide the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile` as theer might be more settings involved).

Comment: would be nice to have `MyCode.h` and `MyCode,cpp` as well or at least small files so we can try to reproduce the problem in the XML files

Comment: OK, I respect that. These files are hypothetical. Here is a complete project with which you can reproduce the problem, including Doxygen Configuration file: https://github.com/chakani/Doxygenator (uses Qt). Look for method 'privateFunc1'. It appears in HTML, but not in XML.

Comment: Which function do you see in the HTML output and not in the XML output? Also mention the HTML page name (from the browser).

Comment: You can see "privateFunc1" and "privateFunc2" in ./html/classc_dox_environ.html, and also in "./xml/classc_dox_environ.xml". However, "privateFunc1", which is defined in mainwindow.cpp, does not have a <location bodyfile=...> in ../xml/classc_dox_environ.xml nor ../xml/mainwindow_8cpp.xml. It's not mentioned anywhere in the latter.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had updated the files. I had not. Please re-download for latest versions.

Comment: That is the latest commit. Can you see "privateFunc1" and "privateFunc2" in mainwindow.h and mainwindow.cpp?

Comment: Try latest commit 82ddd27ed5f8cbdf4e5ec0c34fe852c4920556c8. I'm not familiar with GitHub, fumbling the uploads.

Comment: Reposirory resynced. You mentioned "private functions" but they are "protected". In xml/classc_dox_environ.xml I see: for `privateFunc1`:  `<location file=".../Doxygenator/mainwindow.h" line="67" column="6" bodyfile=".../Doxygenator/mainwindow.cpp" bodystart="1280" bodyend="1282"/>` and for `privateFunc2`: `<location file=".../Doxygenator/mainwindow.h" line="68" column="6" bodyfile=".../Doxygenator/mainwindow.h" bodystart="68" bodyend="70"/>` so this looks OK to me. Did I miss something.

Comment: You are correct, I am seeing `<location bodyfile=...>` in this case. The problem seems to occur with Qt's special `"private slots:"` function type.  I guess that's throwing Doxygen for a loop...

Comment: I've found the error: I'm looking for `kind="function"` and `kind="class"`, but Doxygen is putting out `kind="slot"` for Qt `private slots:` declarations! Thanks for pushing me in the right direction  :o)